# Save selected item from dropdown menu in a meta box as a metadata value for a custom post type

Tags: php, plugin-development, metabox, dropdown, save-post

I have been beating my brains on this one for days now and my Google-fu is failing me.

I have created a custom meta box with a dropdown menu that lists all of the terms from a custom taxonomy. **What I cannot figure out is how to save the selected option from the drop down menu when the post is saved.** I'm a bit of a newb in PHP and though I have found plenty of tutorials and other questions that talk about how to do this, I always get baffled when they get to the part about saving the data.

Here's my code to create the metabox:

```
<?php
function MC_Catalog_create() {
    add_meta_box( 'MC_Catalog_meta', 'Course Information', 'MC_Catalog_course_info','mc_course_post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function MC_Catalog_course_info( $post ) {

$MC_Catalog_course_area = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_MC_Catalog_course_area', true );
$MC_Catalog_course_num = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_MC_Catalog_course_num', true );
$MC_Catalog_course_name = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_MC_Catalog_course_name', true );
$MC_Catalog_course_desc = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_MC_Catalog_course_desc', true );

?>
<table class="form-table" style="width:auto;">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Course Area:</td>
        <td valign="top">
        <select name="MC_Catalog_course_area">
           <?php 
           $myterms = get_terms('course_areas', $args);
                $args = array('orderby'=>'name','order'=>'ASC','hide_empty'=>false);
            foreach($myterms as $term){
                echo "<option value='$term->term_id'" . selected( $term->term_id, $MC_Catalog_course_area, false) .">" . esc_html( $term->name ) . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Course Number:</td>
        <td valign="top"><input name="MC_Catalog_course_num" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $MC_Catalog_course_num ); ?>" size="50" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Course Title:</td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="MC_Catalog_course_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $MC_Catalog_course_name ); ?>" size="50" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Course Description:</td>
        <td valign="top"><textarea name="MC_Catalog_course_desc" rows="8" cols="100"><?php echo esc_attr( $MC_Catalog_course_desc ); ?></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

And here's my code to save the metadata:

```
//hook to save the meta box data
add_action( 'save_post', 'MC_Catalog_save_meta' );

function MC_Catalog_save_meta( $post_id ) {

    //verify the meta data is set
    if ( isset( $_POST['MC_Catalog_course_num'] ) ) {

        //save the meta data
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_MC_Catalog_course_area', strip_tags( $_POST['MC_Catalog_course_area'] ) );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_MC_Catalog_course_num', strip_tags( $_POST['MC_Catalog_course_num'] ) );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_MC_Catalog_course_name', strip_tags( $_POST['MC_Catalog_course_name'] ) );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_MC_Catalog_course_desc', strip_tags( $_POST['MC_Catalog_course_desc'] ) );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98194/73)? It does almost the same, just with another post type instead of a taxonomy.

Comment: @toscho I think that code would answer my question, but I'm still a little mystified as to *how* it works. The bit that goes from if (! $posts) through echo html; just isn't quite clear to me yet. I'm getting close to understanding it. Can you walk me through what each bit is doing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);` returns an array of term objects. Use `$term->term_id` as `option` value …

```
"<option value='$term->term_id'>". esc_html( $term_name ) . "</option>"
```

… and store that ID, not the name. Names can change, the IDs will stay the same – unless someone deletes a term and creates a new one with the same name.

To select the correct option use `selected()`:

```
"<option value='$term->term_id'" . selected( $term->term_id, $MC_Catalog_course_area, FALSE ) .">"
```

You can validate the value with `absint()` then.

Your `save_post` handler needs [more checks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/17392/73).

Comment: Okay - I've updated my original post to include using the ID instead of the name as the value. The HTML it prints out is beautiful, but I still can't figure out how to save that value into my metadata. How do I store the selected option's value when the post is saved?

Comment: I take it back. The data is being saved correctly - I just checked the database tables. 

The problem is, its not setting the default option to the saved option. I thought that's what my If statement was supposed to be doing.

Comment: @TommyParker See my update.

Comment: Thanks. I worked it out after reading up on the selected() function and simplifying everything a little more. I really appreciate your help today.